# Call handler from within function from another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I don't know what's the best way to go about this, or if its even possible, but I have `2` components; a main `NavBar` that goes across the top of the page, and a sidebar `Drawer`.

NavBar:

```
    export default function NavBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <AppBar position="fixed" color="transparent" style={{boxShadow: "none"}}>
              <Toolbar>
                <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} style={{color:"#ee6a2c"}} aria-label="menu" onClick={SideBar.handleDrawerOpen()}>
                  <MenuIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
  );
}
```

In the `onClick` event handler, I want to be able to open the sidebar.

SideBar:

```
export default function SideBar() {

    const classes = useStyles();
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
      };
    
      const handleDrawerClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
      };

    return (
        
        <Drawer
              className={classes.drawer}
              variant="persistent"
              anchor="left"
              open={open}
              classes={{
                paper: classes.drawerPaper,
              }}>
              <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
                <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
                  {theme.direction === 'ltr' ? <ChevronLeftIcon className={classes.drawerIcon}/> : <ChevronRightIcon className={classes.drawerIcon}/>}
                </IconButton>
              </div>

            </Drawer>
    )
}
```

The problem is, I don't know how to pass the function that's in SideBar to be accessible in `NavBar`. Both these components will be part of a larger home page, so is there a better way of going about this, whilst refactoring the code from both out of home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update Added Sample Code Sandbox

[Check out this sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/sidebar-navbar-example-ejmrq)

This becomes more of an opinion based question.

One way to approach this is

Ideally, you shouldn't be having state inside your `SideBar` component. You should only be passing a prop like `visible` which will control whether the `SideBar` opens the drawer or not.

Then instead of doing `onClick={handleDrawerClose}`, you can again use a prop like `onClick={this.props.handleDrawerClose}` which will set the state of `visible` inside the parent component and this `visible` is again passed to the props as described earlier.

This would make your `SideBar` completely controllable from your `ParentComponent` which also has `NavBar` as its child.

Comment: And if I have a button within  SideBar that closes it, how do I pass that change back up to the parent?

Comment: `<IconButton onClick={this.props.handleDrawerClose}>` where `handleDrawerClose` is a function type prop from the parent inside which you will setState for the parent to `visible: false`

Comment: I can provide a code sanbox if it's still unclear for you.

Comment: yes please :). I'm not using classes so not sure how I'm meant to use the `this` keyword.

Comment: oh my bad. you shouldn't use this. You will have to take props in your `SideBar` function like this `export default function SideBar(props) {` and then use it like this `<IconButton onClick={props.handleDrawerClose}>`.

Does this clear the doubt or would you want me to write a basic sample ?

Comment: So when `SideBar` is refactored out of `Parent`, and `handleDrawerClose` is passed through props, it works fine. When `NavBar` is refactored out, and `handleDrawerOpen` is passed through props, it doesn't open the sidebar anymore?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232245/discussion-between-e-god-and-nisanth-reddy).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's interested, here's the code that got it working:

Parent:

```
export default function Home() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [drawerVisible, setDrawerVisible] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleDrawer = () => {
    setDrawerVisible(!drawerVisible);
  };

  const onDrawerClose = () => {
    setDrawerVisible(false);
  };

  return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Paper className={classes.backgroundPaper} style={{minHeight: "70vh"}} square="true">
            <NavBar toggleDrawer={toggleDrawer}></NavBar>
//...
```

NavBar:

```
export default function NavBar(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <AppBar position="fixed" color="transparent" style={{boxShadow: "none"}}>
      <Toolbar>
        <IconButton edge="start" className={classes.menuButton} style={{color:"#ee6a2c"}} aria-label="menu" onClick={props.toggleDrawer}>
          <MenuIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
```

SideBar:

```
export default function SideBar(props) {

    const classes = useStyles();
    
    return (      
        <Drawer
              className={classes.drawer}
              variant="persistent"
              anchor="left"
              open={props.visible}
              classes={{
                paper: classes.drawerPaper,
              }}>
              <div className={classes.drawerHeader}>
                <IconButton onClick={props.onDrawerClose}>
                  {theme.direction === 'ltr' ? <ChevronLeftIcon className={classes.drawerIcon}/> : <ChevronRightIcon className={classes.drawerIcon}/>}
                </IconButton>
              </div>

            </Drawer>
    );
}
```